# Mvc 3 Razor : Using Sections for Partial View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, sections

I defined a section in partial view and I want to specify the content of section from view.
But I can't figure out a way. In asp.net user controls, we can define asp:placeholders, and
specify the content from aspx where user control lies. I'll be glad for any suggestion.

Thanks

[edit]
Here is the asp.net user control and I want to convert it to razor partial view

User control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SpryListView.ascx.cs" Inherits="SpryListView" %>
<div spry:region="<%=this.SpryDataSetName%>" id="region<%=this.ID%>" style="overflow:auto;<%=this.DivStyle%>" >
<table class="searchList" cellspacing="0" style="text-align:left" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="HeaderColumns" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

User control code:

```
public partial class SpryListView : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private string spryDataSetName ;
    private string noDataMessage = "Aradığınız kriterlere uygun kayıt bulunamadı.";
    private bool callCreatePaging;
    private string divStyle;
    private ITemplate headers = null;
    private ITemplate body = null;

    [TemplateContainer(typeof(GenericContainer))]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public ITemplate HeaderTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return headers;
        }
        set
        {
            headers = value;
        }
    }

    [TemplateContainer(typeof(GenericContainer))]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public ITemplate BodyTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return body;
        }
        set
        {
            body = value;
        }
    }

    public string DivStyle
    {
        get { return divStyle; }
        set { divStyle= value; }
    }

    public string NoDataMessage
    {
        get { return noDataMessage; }
        set { noDataMessage = value; }
    }

    public string SpryDataSetName
    {
        get { return spryDataSetName; }
        set { spryDataSetName = value; }
    }

    public bool CallCreatePaging
    {
        get { return callCreatePaging; }
        set { callCreatePaging = value; }
    }

    void Page_Init()
    {
        if (headers != null)
        {
            GenericContainer container = new GenericContainer();
            headers.InstantiateIn(container);
            HeaderColumns.Controls.Add(container);

            GenericContainer container2 = new GenericContainer();
            body.InstantiateIn(container2);
            BodyColumns.Controls.Add(container2);
        }
    }

    public class GenericContainer : Control, INamingContainer
    {
        internal GenericContainer()
        {

        }

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

aspx

```
<spry:listview SpryDataSetName="dsOrders" CallCreatePaging="true" runat="server" ID="orderListView">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>SİPARİŞ TARİHİ</th>
        <th style="text-align:right">GENEL TOPLAM</th>
        <th style="text-align:right">KDV</th>
        <th style="text-align:right">NET TOPLAM</th>
    </HeaderTemplate>  
 </spry:listview>
```

[edit]

I want to do exactly this in mvc 3 razor partial view.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Templated Razor Delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx/) seem to be what you're after. They essentially let your helpers take the template (your delegate) as an argument you pass in from the view. This way it is the caller (your view) that controls the way information is rendered, not the helper, thus giving you more flexibility.

Comment: Link was broken. Working link: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/26/templated-razor-delegates.aspx/

Answer (score 4):

You should take a `Func<object, HelperResult>` as a parameter to the partial view.
In the parent view, you can pass HTML like `@<div>...</div>` as the parameter.

In the partial view, you can call the delegate with any parameter to render the HTML.